# Deleted Data_Stax and now no test Methods/Classes/etc. within javasrc/src

Tags: eclipse, datastax-enterprise

Eclipse and playOrm was running great, I finally got Cassandra running, and the test cases were compiling (running/debugging).

In the process of getting Cassandra running, I downloaded Data_Stax, which I figured was pointless, because Cassandra was probably running all along, I was just waiting for something more to appear than the "Listening for thrifts clients" message in the dos window.

That being said, today I deleted Data_Stax, and now when recreating the Java Project: from the AntBuild, my .java methods and classes no longer appear in the "Package Explorer" view.

[image: No .java files at "javasrc", or "src"]

All the .JAR library files are populating...

[image: Expanded Library view]

And the error message reads...
[image]

Does this have something to do with removing Data_Stax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, forgot to run the .bat file, populating the library and files...